# Updating table information formatting based on a checkbox value

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table that contains a list of items taken from a SQL database using php.  There is a checkbox, Done, that I want to tick off as the list is completed.  I want the text of the associated item to update to grey or strikethrough as the box is ticked off.

I tried using one of the methods as above:
In CSS

```
:checked + span {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

In HTML

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="db-table">

<td><input type="checkbox" name="Done1" value="1" <?php if ($info['Done1'] ==1) echo 'checked'; ?>></td>
    <span>
    <td><?php echo $info['Seq1'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $info['Size1'];?></td>
    </span>

</table>
```

It does not work.  The table has further CSS formatting based on the class.
I take the same data, put it outside the table tags, and it works just fine.
Any suggestions of what to do here?  Is the table class somehow overriding what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is invalid, you can't nest a `span` directly within a table like that and you're also missing the `<tr>` tags.

However, even with valid markup, what you're asking isn't possible with CSS alone as it doesn't provide any means (yet) for selecting parent elements, which would need to be done here in order to target the sibling cells or parent row.

So, you're going to have to resort to a bit of JavaScript, toggling a class on the parent row each time a checkbox is clicked.

Before we get to the Snippet, here's what you'd need to do with your PHP in order to have the `.done` class applied to the table rows that require it initially:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="db-table">
    <tr<?php if ($info['Done1'] ==1) echo ' class="done"';?>>
        <td>
            <input<?php if ($info['Done1'] ==1) echo ' checked="checked"';?> type="checkbox" name="Done1" value="1">
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $info['Seq1'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['Size1'];?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here's a working Snippet to demonstrate the solution:

```js
var inputs=document.querySelector(".db-table").getElementsByTagName("input"),x=inputs.length;
while(x--)
 inputs[x].addEventListener("click",function(){
  this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.toggle("done");
 },0);
```

```css
.done td{
    font-weight:bold;
}

/* Just some prettifying */table{border:1px solid #999;border-spacing:1px;font-family:arial;font-size:14px;margin:0 auto;width:50%;}td{line-height:20px;padding:5px;}td:first-child{text-align:center;width:20px;}tr:nth-child(odd) td{background:#eee;}tr:nth-child(even) td{background:#ddd;}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="db-table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Done1" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Done2" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Done3" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The piece of code: <tr<?php if ($info['Done1'] ==1) echo ' class="done"';?>> was exactly what I needed to achieve the task.  I'm not necessarily worried about real-time updating upon clicking the box, but it's when the status of the box is read from the database i'm concerned about displaying the items asociated with the box.  It works great.  Thank you.

Comment: Ha-ha! The one thing I wasn't trying to answer! Besides it not being 100% clear from your question, I'm not a PHP guy, I just thought I'd give that bit a stab for the sake of completeness. Glad to be of help :) If I've answered your question to your satisfaction, could you accept the answer, please?

Comment: Rereading your question, with the clarification in your comment above, it's now clearer to me what you were asking. I'm a bit pressed for time today but, when/if I get a minute, I'll rewrite my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. You're CSS will never show because your span is never inside of your checkbox (:check).

At this point you will start getting into DOM Elements. The following example uses JavaScript/jQuery. I set up a listener to listen for checkbox changes (ie is it checked or not). If the checkbox is checked then I add a "done" class onto `.info` classes.

In order to know which row I'm dealing with I've added to HTML tags. 1, I've added an id to the `tr`. This should always be unique to the row. 2, I've added a `data-row` to the checkbox element. This is used to identify the row.

JavaScript is great to use in this instance because you are wanting to change elements on the fly that are outside of the hierarchy that CSS allows.

It may be a little over the top, but it definitely gets the job done.

```
<?php
$info['Done1'] = 0;
$info['Seq1'] = 'Hello';
$info['Size1'] = 'World';
?>

<style type="text/css">
.done{color:#ccc;}
</style>

<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="db-table">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Done1" value="1" data-row="1" <?php if ($info['Done1'] ==1) echo 'checked'; ?>></td>
        <td class="info"><?php echo $info['Seq1'];?></td>
        <td class="info"><?php echo $info['Size1'];?></td>  
    </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input[name="Done1"]').change(function(){
        if( this.checked ){
            $('#row'+$(this).data('row')+' .info').addClass('done');
        }else{
            $('#row'+$(this).data('row')+' .info').removeClass('done');
        }       
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why have you gone for jQuery here. The question gives no indication that jQuery is being used. You can do exactly what you've done in pure JavaScript without the unnecessary added bloat of the jQuery file.

Comment: If you'd like to submit an answer please do so. This was my solution.

Comment: I'm not faulting the solution, I'd do exactly the same, just with plain JavaScript. All I'm pointing out is that jQuery should not be the immediate go-to if the question does not indicate that it is already in use or that its use is an option.